# Scroll on fixed div isn't working properly

Tags: html, css, scroll, styles

my problem is that I have a fixed div which is my responsive navigation. And when that div is opened, I want to have a properly scroll if screen has smaller height from list in div. But that isn't working.
[image]
Like the browser don't count a last select button, and when I resize browser window over the select button then I have a scroll bar.
[image]
I don't know what is mean that dashed line (chrome developer tools), but I have a feel that's a problem.

**EDIT:** I just add `height:calc(100vh + 60px), padding-bottom:60px` on that .responsiveNav element and that's solve my problem friends :D

Comment: Please add your code and images here. It is not ideal to redirect users to a different URL. Few users might skip this question because of the extra click.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro for suggestion :)